# JSON.NET, instantiate fallback object if expected object fails to deserialize

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have a tree of items that I'm trying to deserialize using JSON.NET. There are cases, such as renaming node types, where a node on the tree might fail to deserialize.

In these cases, I'd like to insert a default instance of a node (likely some other type) in place of the object that did not deserialize.

This way, my users can still load their save files, getting an "empty" node they would have to fix up... But, at least they could still load their file!

I have been doing a bunch of research, and have some things to try with SerializationBinder and/or hacking some error handling in the callback on the serializer, but I feel inclined to ask, in case there is some obvious solution that I'm missing, or input about those approaches.

In case it matters, this is an internal tool that is rapidly evolving, we expect some broken trees every now and then, we really just wish they would load, regardless :)

Thanks!

Comment: You also want the "empty" node to have the text of the node which failed to deserialize and any children which were prevented from deserializing because of the parent failure.

Comment: What is the failure mode? If it fails because the node is badly formatted (missing braces for example), it is programatically extremely difficult to figure out where to start resuming the parsing (ie where the end of the corruptions occured)

Comment: @Trisped Yes, that's true!  I think I can use a [JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) to store the intermediate values. Regarding the descendents, the tree object itself happens to have references to them, and will be able to deserialize them--only the connections will have to be re-established.

Comment: @Uebercoder The JSON itself will typically have integrity; it is saved and loaded using the same application and technology. The error will generally be that a node's qualified type has changed.  That seems to be the prevailing issue we have. With a solution like this, we would be well positioned to apply the same technique to other issues as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured something out, with much thanks to dozens of other posts here!

**Node base class** decorated with JsonConverter

```
[JsonObject( IsReference = true, TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All )]
[JsonConverter( typeof( ChainNodeConverter ))]
public abstract class Node
{
    public List< Node > Children { get; set; }
}
```

**ErrorNode class** has some properties to help id/restore the failed node

```
public class ErrorNode : Node
{
    public JToken JToken { get; set; }
    public string FailedTypeString { get; set; }
}
```

**NodeConverer class**

```
public class NodeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType ) { return typeof( Node ).IsAssignableFrom( objectType ); }


    public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("If CanWrite is false; this won't be called.");
    }


    public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        var jToken = JToken.ReadFrom( reader );

        var refString = jToken.Value< string >( "$ref" );
        var firstReference = refString == null;

        if ( firstReference )
        {
            var typeString = jToken.Value<string>( "$type" );

            if ( typeString != null )
            {
                var type = Type.GetType( typeString );

                if ( type == null )
                {
                    var errorNode = new ErrorNode();

                    errorNode.JToken = jToken;
                    errorNode.FailedTypeString = typeString;

                    // Apply the old node's relationships to errorNode
                    serializer.Populate( jToken.CreateReader(), errorNode );

                    return errorNode;
                }
            }
        }

        // Default-like behaviour
        return serializer.Deserialize( jToken.CreateReader() );
    }
}
```